# Check substring of a string

Tags: c, string, substring, arrays

I'm trying to check whether or not the second argument in my program is a substring of the first argument. The problem is that it only work if the substring starts with the same letter of the string.

EDIT: It must be done in C, not C++.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf ("Usage: check <string one> <string two>\n");
    }

    int result = my_strstr(argv[1], argv[2]);

    if(result == 1){
        printf("%s is a substring of %s\n", argv[2], argv[1]);
    }
    else{
        printf("%s is not a substring of %s\n", argv[2], argv[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: … specifically, homework which forbids you to use any library functions besides `at`?

Comment: When you pass strings to functions, use 'const string&'.

Comment: Why is the standard C strstr function not acceptable?

Comment: Please don't edit questions in a way that answers already given are invalidated.

Comment: Where's the definition of `my_strstr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis of the problem ("it only work if the substring starts with the same letter of the string") is incorrect and so you are looking for the wrong problem.  Since this appears to be homework, I'll just hint at the underlying problem.

While it fails with `Michigan` and `igan` it will correctly work with `Michigan` and `higan`.

Why does it work for `higan` and not `igan`?  What is the first letter of `igan`?  What is different about that when it comes to `Michigan`?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming homework, so: Take a look at what `subStart` is initialized with.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm isn't correct.

What you want is nested loops. Loop over the length of `str`, then loop over the length of `sub` to see if there is a match starting at that position.